# Trying to change array value in MIPS assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I was hoping that I could get some help debugging some code. I am going to try to not make this a It is for a MIPS assembly project in recursion.  The program is only supposed to print prime numbers.
 The idea is I have two arrays, one that lists every whole number up to 110, and the other as a flag array that is initialized to all ones.
  For every position in the flag array that is a 1 it prints the number and every 0 it doesn't print the number.  The good news is I figured out issues with all my loops, the issue I am having is saving the value 0 to the flag array at the position it currently is.  Everything that I reference talks about using:

```
sw [register], ([register])
```

From what I understand that is how you save the contents of one register to the position of the other?  It doesn't seem to work for me.  I went ahead and posted the code down bellow, It is kind of messy and really long, but my code for recursion is down where it says Eratosthenes.

```
.data

NUM_ARRAY:  .space 800   # 800-byte memory space
FLAG_ARRAY: .space 800   # 800-byte memory space

START_MSG: .asciiz   "The prime numbers up to 110 are:\n"
END_MSG:   .asciiz   "Completed ...."
SPACE:     .asciiz   "  "
NEWLINE:   .asciiz   "\n"
BUG1:     .asciiz   "Out of loop"
INK:      .asciiz   "incrementK"
INX:      .asciiz   "incrementX"
.text
.globl main

# THE BEGINNING OF MODULE MAIN #######################
main:
    # save the ten registers --------------------------
    subu  $sp, $sp, 48    # stack frame for 12 registers

    sw    $ra,   ($sp)
    sw    $s0,  4($sp)
    sw    $s1,  8($sp)
    sw    $s2, 12($sp)
    sw    $s4, 16($sp)
    sw    $s5, 20($sp)
    sw    $t0, 24($sp)
    sw    $t1, 28($sp)
    sw    $t2, 32($sp)
    sw    $v0, 36($sp)
    sw    $a0, 40($sp)

    # initialize the essential parameters -------------
    li    $s0, 111         # the largest number (always - 1)
    li    $s1, 10          # the square-root of $s0 register
    li    $s2, 2           # the initial value for "k"
    li    $s4, 0           # the first numbers to consider
    li    $s5, 1           # '1' - it is a prime number

    li    $t2, 0           # loop ounter

# show an opening message ---------------------------------
    li    $v0, 4           # system call #4
    la    $a0, START_MSG
    syscall

# initialize the two arrays -------------------------------
    la    $t0, NUM_ARRAY   # set the address of the 1st array
    la    $t1, FLAG_ARRAY  # set the address of the 2nd array

loop1:  sw    $s4, ($t0)       # load a number
    sw    $s5, ($t1)       # load the initial property (1 - a prime)

    addi  $t2, $t2, 1      # increase the loop counter by one

    beq   $t2, $s0, EXIT1  # if all the array elements are set up

    addi  $s4, $s4, 1      # increase the number by one

    addu  $t0, $t0, 4      # increase the pointer by four bytes
    addu  $t1, $t1, 4      # increase the pointer by four bytes

    j     loop1            # repeat to "loop1"

EXIT1:  li $s2, 2
    li $s6, 2

    jal   Eratosthenes     # start recursive Eratosthenes

    li    $v0, 4           # system call #4
    la    $a0, NEWLINE
    syscall
    li    $v0, 4           # system call #4
    la    $a0, NEWLINE
    syscall

    li    $t2, 0           # reset the loop counter

    la    $t0, NUM_ARRAY   # reset the address of the 1st array
    la    $t1, FLAG_ARRAY  # reset the address of the 2nd array

loop3:  lw    $a0, ($t1)        # load the number there
    beq   $a0, $zero, SKIP1 # if the target is '0': skip
    beq   $t2, $zero, SKIP1 # if repeated enough: skip

    li    $v0, 1           # system call #1
    lw    $a0, ($t0)       # load the number there
    syscall

    li    $v0, 4           # system call #4
    la    $a0, NEWLINE
    syscall

SKIP1:  addi  $t2, $t2, 1      # increase the loop counter

    addu  $t0, $t0, 4      # increase the pointer by four bytes
    addu  $t1, $t1, 4      # increase the pointer by four bytes

    blt   $t2, $s0, loop3

    li    $v0, 4           # system call #4
    la    $a0, END_MSG
    syscall

# restore registers ---------------------------------------
    lw    $ra,   ($sp)
    lw    $s0,  4($sp)
    lw    $s1,  8($sp)
    lw    $s2, 12($sp)
    lw    $s4, 16($sp)
    lw    $s5, 20($sp)
    lw    $t0, 24($sp)
    lw    $t1, 28($sp)
    lw    $t2, 32($sp)
    lw    $v0, 36($sp)
    lw    $a0, 40($sp)

    addu  $sp, $sp, 48     # delete the stack frame

    jr    $31              # park it at the parking spot

# THE END OF MODULE MAIN ##########################################

Eratosthenes:
        subu $sp,$sp,36

        sw $ra, 0($sp)
        sw $t5, 4($sp)
        sw $t6, 8($sp)
        sw $t0, 12($sp)
        sw $t1, 16($sp)
        sw $t2, 20($sp)
        sw $s4, 24($sp)
        sw $s5, 28($sp)
        sw $s0, 32($sp)

        li $s5, 0 #change s5 to 0
        li $s6, 2 #reset the x
        li $t2, 0
        la $t0, NUM_ARRAY #reset Array 1
        la $t1, FLAG_ARRAY #reset Array 2

R_Loop:
        mult $s2,$s6
        mflo $t7
        addi $t2,$t2,1


        lw $s4, ($t0)

        beq $t7, $s4, SKIPone
        beq $t2, $s0, EXITL #branch if counter is max

        addu $t0, $t0, 4 #next spot in NUM_ARRAY
        addu $t1, $t1, 4 #next spot in FLAG_ARRAY

        li $v0,1
        move $a0, $t7
        syscall

        li $v0,4
        la $a0, NEWLINE
        syscall

        li $v0,4
        la $a0, NEWLINE
        syscall



        j R_Loop
SKIPone:
        addi $s6,$s6,1 #increment x by one

        sw $zero, ($t1) #attempt at making position at array 0
        #have also tried 
        #sw $s5, ($t1) #where s5 is initialized at 0
        #please take note that offset is 0, because it needs to be
        #at the current position at the array

        li $v0,4
        la $a0, NEWLINE
        syscall

        li $v0,4
        la $a0, NEWLINE
        syscall

        li $v0,1
        move $a0, $t4 #debug aid
        syscall

        li $v0,4
        la $a0, NEWLINE
        syscall

        li $v0,4
        la $a0, NEWLINE
        syscall

        beq $t2 $s0, EXITL
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, INX  #debug aid
        syscall

        j R_Loop
EXITL:      
        li $t8,10

        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, INK #debug aid
        syscall

        beq $s2,$t8, EXITR
        addi $s2,$s2,1 #increment k by one
        jal Eratosthenes
        li $v0 4
        la $a0, BUG1
        syscall

EXITR:


        lw $ra, 0($sp)
        lw $t5, 4($sp)
        lw $t6, 8($sp)
        lw $t0, 12($sp)
        lw $t1, 16($sp)
        lw  $t2, 20($sp)
        lw $s4, 24($sp)
        lw $s5, 28($sp)
        lw $s0, 32($sp)
        addu $sp,$sp,36

        jr $ra
```

Any help is appreciated, nothing else seems to work and my teacher is of no help.

Comment: Looks about right. Define "It doesn't seem to work for me". Also use your debugger/simulator to single step the code and see where exactly it deviates from what you intended.

Comment: so, if I print the number that is supposed to be saved in $t1, by moving it and trying to print after, nothing gets printed, also my teacher didn't really show us how to read PCspim, the client we use to run the code.  I have been debugging by printing different keywords, which is why it says things like, "incrementX"  that is how my teacher said to debug my code and offered no more help after that.

Comment: OKAY, so I am stupid.  I have been running a different file this whole time....... the program posted above is the one i've been modifying..... I am not sure how that happened.  I appreciate your time though Jester....

Comment: Didn't read through it, but there seems to be chapter(s) about debugging: https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi12/cse141-a/demos/spim/PCSpim-Tutorial.pdf  Debugging assembly by printing debug output is both worse and more error prone, it actually takes quite some experience and deep assembly knowledge to fully understand all consequences of debug output in asm, debugging like that for example some multi-thread issues can mislead you to wrong assumptions easily. Although in simple code like prime sieve it's just ordinarily tricky, not super tricky. (still learning to use debugger is much safer)